# GCP Dataflow jobs failure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

Following error is being shown:

Workflow failed. Causes: Error: Message: Invalid value for field 'resource.properties.networkInterfaces[0].subnetwork': 'regions/xxxxx-xxxx/subnetworks/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx'. The project 'projects' was not found. HTTP Code: 400

Please anyone suggest what caused this error.

Solution: Do not need to change anything. This error fix on its own after few times. Seems to be a google's global issue.

Comment: I am having the same problem.

Comment: @BrunoVolpato: Please could you share your error message here. I just need to check whether the "**The project 'projects' was not found. HTTP Code: 400**" error is showing there or not.

Comment: The exact same message. It seems to be resolved now. *"Workflow failed. Causes: Error: Message: Invalid value for field 'resource.properties.networkInterfaces[0].subnetwork': 'regions/us-west1/subnetworks/subnet-{name}'. The project 'projects' was not found. HTTP Code: 400"*

Comment: @BrunoVolpato: Thats great !! What exactly you do to fix it, could you please share with me.

Comment: Nothing. The jobs we were sending it failed, we just submitted again and it is working fine now. We are using Beam SDK 2.14.0.

Comment: @BrunoVolpato it is working for me also. Just tried after you mentioned. Thanks.It seems to be google's global issue.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same error and already solved it. Not sure what caused it but try our solution to see if it serves you.

We changed the Subnetwork parameter from short form to complete URL.

source: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/specifying-networks#subnetwork_parameter

Comment: Thanks for your response. The jobs are working fine till last night, today morning itself, it started failing with this error message. So I am not sure changing from short to complete URL will help or not. I will give a try. Also could you please confirm whether the error include this message also in your case i.e: "**The project 'projects' was not found. HTTP Code: 400**"

Comment: This issue resolved without doing any changes. Rerun the jobs and jobs are now completing.